# Custom validator dynamic message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I want custom validator dynamic messages. Custom validator for required field and regular expression. I don't want to use required field validator and regular expression validator it creates more problems for me.
***Here is javascript code***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckMyText(sender, args) {
        var compare = RegExp("^.{1,10}$");
        args.IsValid = compare.test(args.Value)
            return;
    }
</script>
```

***Here is custom validator and text field code***

```
<asp:TextBox ID="summary" runat="server" Width="627px" CssClass="texrbox"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="CheckMyText" ControlToValidate="summary" ErrorMessage="" Text="*" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

It is working fine but I want to show message when regular expression error fired ***Only 10 characters allowed*** and for required field I want to show ***Required Field***. How to do it. I want to show bith messages in validation summary.

Answer (score 0):

A validator renders as a `<span>` element in html. So you can use that to change your error message.

```
document.getElementById('<%= CustomValidator2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "My custom error msg";
```

Or change the ErrorMessage:

```
<%= CustomValidator2.ClientID %>.errormessage = "Error for summary";
```

Comment: I want to show error is validation summary. and what to do for required field

Comment: Updated my answer, and if you want required change the regex to fail on empty content or check yourself in `CheckMyText`